# Filter list based on condition that it contains two contradicting strings

Tags: r, list, filter

```
my_list = list()
my_list[[1]] = c("Fast","Slow","Heavy","Light")
my_list[[2]] = c("Fast","Small","Intelligent","Light")
my_list[[3]] = c("Dumb","Slow","Heavy","Light")
my_list[[4]] = c("Slow","Intelligent","Dumb","Heavy")
my_list[[5]] = c("Heavy","Light","Intelligent","Tall")
```

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to do, but how can I filter a list so that if two strings are contained within it (ie. Fast and Slow, Tall and Small, Heavy and Light, lastly, Intelligent and Dumb), then they can are removed to leave a final vector with sensible vectors.

I have been trying to do this with an IF function, is that the most appropriate way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What's the desired output for this sample. How is R supposed to know which words are opposites/contradictions?

Comment: The only output would be my_list[[2]] since it doesnt have any of the pairs of strings listed below.  Fast(not slow), Small(not tall), Intelligent(not dumb) and Light(not heavy).  But basically I want to know how to reduce a list with an IF function so that all lists are removed that contain two certain words.

Comment: so you need something like `(a1 & b1) or (a2 & b2) or (a3 & b3)`

Comment: First, put your "contradicting strings" into an R object, like a data.frame... Eventually (when you have this sanely formatted) it might be as simple as a merge, I guess.

Comment: Yeah exactlythat

Answer (score 0):

This would be what you want:

```
cont_check <- function(x) {
    cont_words <- list(c("Fast", "Slow"),
                       c("Heavy", "Light"))
    found <- sum(sapply(cont_words, function (y) sum(y %in% x) == 2)) > 0 
    return(found)
}
sapply(my_list, cont_check)
# select ones
# my_list[!sapply(my_list, cont_check)]
```